# Boot iMac from Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, startup, ssd, target-disk-mode

The new MacBooks are the best

[image]

But their processors are pretty anemic. Not a big deal when I'm out and about, but not great for serious work.

## What I'd like to do:

**Get an iMac with decent specs, use its processor, RAM, etc., and boot from my Macbook's SSD.**

## What I've tried:

It looks like Target Disk Mode could accomplish this, but several things are unclear:

1. Would that even boot, or just allow me to browse the Macbook's SSD?
2. Could I use the Macbook as a secondary display? Feels a shame to waste it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can boot an iMac from the Mac Book volume using Target Disk Mode. The main issue to be aware of is many programs will ask you to log in again, including App Store apps.